# Not getting the bottom tab click

Tags: android, navigation

I am using bottom tab with right side navigation. For navigation i am using `DrawerLayout` Check my below code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HomeTabFragement">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/tittlesetting" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_sidemenu"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/settingbutton_bg" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I am getting the DrawerLayout only

[image]

Comment: Your question lacks the expected and actual results. You should tell (draw) us exactly what you expect and/or where the wrong parts are.

Comment: @try-catch-finally : i am getting the sliding menu . But the problem is that i am not getting the bottom tab click . It is because the Drawable layout is above the tab fragment. How am i suppose to use both the tab and sliding menu simultaneously?

Comment: Instead of creating Fragment you can try to create a layout with buttons as tab or you can try with coordinator layout.